# Documents being erroneously approved on insert

Tags: permissions, wss-2.0

I have a process that inserts hundreds or thousands of documents a day into a WSS 2.0 site. Recently a developer who is no longer employed with us made a change to enable some approval functionality if an item meets certain criteria - that worked.

However a side effect of a change I've yet to uncover is that now all documents inserted into the site are approved upon insert. I've removed the code that he had added, but something else is still affecting the approval status.

The Time stamp on the file meta data for creation and last modified is exactly the same, so I know that it's not a process running after insertion doing this. The code that is inserting the file has no approval of any sort in it.

I'm thinking there has to be some sort of setting or permission in WSS 2.0 that approves a file upon insertion. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I should add that the user the insert process is running as has the "Contributor" group security permissions. I am currently researching whether this group is set to the default security permissions or if it has been modified.

Comment: Could this be a workflow?

Comment: Is there any event receiver, timer job, associated workflow? If you use some kind of versioning system I'd go there and search for modification your employee did and compare it with previous copy. My first try would be to contact the ex employee.

Comment: I don't believe WSS 2.0 has workflows. I don't know what you mean by event receiver (Though this sounds promising, I'm going to go google), but I do know that there is only one job running at the time that these files are created. That code has no mention of approvals, nor the moderation object in general in it. We have a versioning system... this code is not in it... of course. Unfortunately contacting the employee is out of the question.

Comment: WSS 2.0 does not have workflows. This would be some sort of custom solution. I'm not familiar with WSS 2.0, but if it is anything like MOSS 2007 or SharePoint 2010, you should have access to Central Administration. I'd go there, and look and see what solutions have been deployed to your farm. One of them, may be associated with the particular event receiver that's triggering these approvals.

Comment: Are you sure approval is turned on? Also, you say you removed the custom code the developer had created. Where did this code hook into WSS? WSS 2.0 doesn't have event receivers nor workflow. So how did his code get triggered? Or is it some batch process running in the background? Also, did you reboot/ISSRESET after removing that custom code?

Comment: Is there a condition on the approval if it is custom, and does the user who they are inserted as set the approval as done and/or not require approval. To many variables to give an answer.

Comment: The code that I removed was a background process that used the object model to approve docs based on certain conditions. I'm still unclear what was approving the documents after I removed that code, but the approval was happening at the exact time of insertion - so I know it wasn't some lingering code in the background process changing it (They run several hours apart). Anyhow, I did fix it. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm still unclear what exactly was auto approving documents upon insertion, removing the admin rights of the user doing the insertion immediately fixed the issue. I don't know if this was built in SP functionality or some other code that runs concurrently with the insert, but as the approvals happen at the exact time of insertion, or the documents are inserted approved already, I'm leaning towards built in SP functionality for documents inserted by an Administrator.

Please comment if you disagree. I would like to have a definitive understanding, even after fixing the issue.