# Determine what happens when a document inserted into library

Tags: document-library, wss-2.0

We have a WSS 2.0 site that's auto approving documents as they are inserted into the library. you can see more about this situation at my other question: [Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60332/documents-being-erroneously-approved-on-insert)

One of the commenters mentioned I look for event receivers, workflows, or timer jobs. My question is in WSS 2.0, how can I determine what if anything happens when a document is inserted? How can I check if an event receiver is attached to a list? A workflow? (though I read there are no workflows in WSS 2.0) Other possibilities?

Is there a place where events are registered, or something of that sort?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've worked with WSS 2.0/SharePoint 2003 but what I remember is the ONLY event receivers that were possible were for document libraries.  And I think there was a box under document library settings and then advanced settings where you put in the event receiver assembly.  That's where I would look.  There wouldn't be any eventreceivers for a list item because it couldn't be done in that version.

Comment: I think this is correct, however I was unable to confirm it due to the crazy customization that was done to this site. The settings page is physically not present. Yay for inheriting code. Marking as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free tool on CodePlex to check attached Event receivers,

http://speventreceiverman.codeplex.com/

I am not 100% sure if it will work on SP 2003 or not but work giving it a go.

Comment: Umm, this is SP 2003, I don't think you can control SP 2003 with powershell.

Comment: @SteveLineberry ahh, I didn't realized that, but PS can be installed based on Operating System not SharePoint version, so if Dakine got Windows Server 2003 or Windows XP SP2/SP3 or so on, he can install PS version 1, but then I am not sure if above script will def gonna work.

Comment: Yea, I don't think the get-spweb commandlet will be there.